# Recursive error encountered when updating rules of assignment

Tags: functions, recursion, placeholder

I'm working on a problem which requires associating a single (complex) number with a pair of binary vectors. I'm doing this by creating a set of assignments through a function I call `NormMap`, which takes as input a pair of binary vectors and returns the associated complex number. In the problem I'm considering, these vectors are generated through a procedure whose nature is irrelevant for this question. Once a pair of vectors is generated, I check to see if that pair has already been produced. If not, create a new association in `NormMap` for these vectors. If they have been created previously, simply add the new complex number associated with this pair to the old complex number.

It is this addition process which is creating problems, and leads to a recursive error that I can't understand. Given a pair of vectors `s1` and `s2`, I have tried

`If[ValueQ[NormMap[s1+s2]], NormMap[s1+s2] += ...`

inside of a function which is passed `s1` and `s2`, and where `...` indicates what I am adding to the previously assigned value. The problem seems to be that `+=` can't be used here (for some reason) to update the assignment. I've tried this with simpler cases outside of functions, and not had any issues. For example, calling

`f[0] = 1; f[0]+=1; f[0]`

returns 2, as expected. The error message associated with this problem is a recursive one, so Mathematica must be trying to relate `NormMap[s1+s2]` to itself implicitly, instead of accessing the assigned value and updating it. I've tried using `Evaluate` and `ReleaseHold` to no effect - can anyone explain how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: We may need more information on your code to provide meaningful and pertinent advice...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't guarantee this without seeing a faithful, minimal example of your code, but...

ValueQ[NormMap[s1+s2]] is probably always returning True. ValueQ does not tell you that an expression resolves to something you might think of as atomic. From the documentation:

> With the default method, Automatic, ValueQ[expr] effectively uses "OwnValuesPresent" if expr is a symbol and "SymbolDefinitionsPresent" otherwise.

And SymbolDefinitionsPresent is interpreted as meaning "one or more symbols have any sort of definition present".

With a brand new session, I evaluated this:

```
ValueQ[NormMap[s1 + s2]]
```

and the result was True. What I think is happening here, based on my reading of the documentation, is that there is a symbol in the expression `s1+s2` that has something defined for it. The FullForm of the expression is `Plus[s1, s2]`, and Plus certainly has a definition.

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed in the documentation that the behavior seems to have been changed/augmented since version 12.1, so your version might be important here.